# Indian Passport not stamped, arriving from Canada via Amtrak

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, officials

I was travelling back on the Amtrak train to New York from Montreal after a 3 day stay. On the way back, the CBP officer didn't even check my passport. Neither did he check the passport of the person sitting next to me and ahead of me.

What should I do about this if anything? I have an entry stamp in my passport for Canada, but no entry stamp for USA.

I checked my I94 on the website, and it says I entered on 4th April and exited on 27th May, but no entry for today(29th May).

Edit:

If it helps, I'm here on an F-1 visa.

Update:

I called the CBP office at JFK airport(the number for Philadelphia airport is unreachable) and they said that since my stay in Canada was just for 2 days my old I94 is still valid and that I didn't need to do anything about it.

Final update:

I just got admitted to the US again. So I guess there wasn’t a problem in the first place. I still am holding onto my tickets and documents just in case I need them in the future, but this doesn’t seem to be an issue since I just re-entered the US. Very bizarre and nerve-wracking experience, but it turned out to be alright.

Comment: You still have to follow what @crazydre wrote. You're **not illegal** however you need to get it fixed. US immigration can be very screwy and you want to err on the side of caution. Nothing to panic about **at all** because you did nothing wrong and you have proof (Amtrak tickets & pass **keep it**) of entry. I've been through the whole US Immigration from B to F1 to H1B through Permanent Residence and Citizenship so I know how you're feeling however this will be resolved in five minutes. You can email them today too if you want to, you won't get an answer but just for the record.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59601/discussion-on-question-by-atharva-vaidya-indian-passport-not-stamped-arriving-f).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What the officers did (not checking and registering everyone) was illegal, and unfortunately it's always the traveller that gets to pay for it.

You must go ***tomorrow morning*** to the deferred inspections site located at  Philadelphia Airport, terminal A West, open Monday-Friday 09:00-12:00, and present your visa in the passport, I-20 form, and the train ticket to the US. They will take the necessary steps to Register your entry in the records.

To get to the airport, take the SEPTA train from central Philadelphia.

Comment: Although your suggested remedy is correct, he is **not** in the USA illegally. http://asianjournal.com/immigration/being-waved-across-the-border-could-constitute-inspection-for-adjustment-of-status/. There is a case in immigration court which covers this situation. Of course OP does not need the hassle of having to go through immigration court one day to correct this oversight, hence should follow your solution.

Comment: `In a case published by the Board of Immigration Appeals (BIA), a person approached the border as a passenger in a car being driven by her US citizen friend. The immigration inspector asked the friend whether he was a US citizen, but did not ask the passenger anything. The officer then waved the car through the port of entry. Eventually, the person married a US citizen, and the issue was whether being waved through the border constituted “inspection. The BIA ruled that being waved through the border constituted inspection and admission to the US`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The earliest I can make it to one of those locations when they are open is on Wednesday(day after tomorrow). Would that be a problem?

Comment: @AtharvaVaidya Should be OK. Where in the US are you now?

Comment: I'm still on the Amtrak train. It's in upstate New York right now.

Comment: @AtharvaVaidya And where are you on your way to? So I can locate the correct centre

Comment: Final destination is Philadelphia. I'm supposed to reach today by 23:30.

Comment: @AtharvaVaidya Check the update, I wrote the address

Comment: what a generous and useful answer!

Comment: (I would have just said "yeah go get a stamp buddy"  :-) )

Comment: @Fattie Here on Travelstack one-liners are not accepted as answers

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie: Just because someone entered with inspection doesn't mean they are currently in the US legally.

Comment: @user102008 Well, if their F1 visa was valid when they entered, **or** they spent less than 30 days outside the US but in the WHTI area, they're in the US legally for as long as the I20 is valid.

Comment: @user102008 I believe we all know that. We're sticking with the details the OP provided. We cannot conjecture/speculate about other issues he might have that we know nothing about and which he didn't mention.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie: I am not talking about any other issues. The case you brought up is the Matter of Quilantan which says that even someone who was never admitted into any legal status can have entered with inspection. That's not relevant to this question at all. Whether the entry is with inspection is not the issue here. The issue is whether the OP was admitted into F1 status, and Matter of Quilantan doesn't help with that at all, as Quilantan was not admitted into a legal status when he entered, and was in the US illegally from the moment of entry.

Comment: @user102008 Did you even follow the chain of the discussion or you're just jumping in midstream? I posted the case because the original answer (which has since been edited) said he was illegal and accruing illegal presence because he didn't get an I94 and was not admitted etc and I was pointing out that being waved in can be accepted as admitted and inspected and hence he is not illegal. The worst casewould be he is out of status. If you followed the development of the whole question and answer and comments, you would follow. In any case if you have a better answer than Crazydre, post it.